# How to create popup using jquery

Tags: jquery, dialog

I want to create dialog using jQuery, which can create like and object in java.

```
var popupObject = $.popup({option1:'dd', option2: 'ccc'});
```

Then I can control popup like this:

```
popupObject.show();
popupObject.hide();
```

I need this coding style for apply to JSF controlling.

How can I coding in jQuery?

Please help me, I search for long time.

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery UI Dialog widget? I think it should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many good pop up box functionality for jQuery here is a [list or **10**](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/10-jquery-popup-window-image-slider-plugins/) various popup box with ready source code and Demo,
 you can also try [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```